# How to pass value from one servlet to another servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I've two Servlets namely `S1` and `S2`. `S1` contains a variable `x` of String type, `S2` contains a variable `y` of String type.I have a method `m(x,y)` implemented in class `C`.How can i pass `x` or `y`  to Servlet (`S2` or `S1`) using method `m(x,y)`?

Comment: `request.setAttribute`

Comment: Stop thinking in "passing". Start thinking in "scopes" (request scope, session scope and application scope). Simply put data in the desired scope and elswehere check/grab data there. Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-shared-variables-and-multithreading

Answer (score 2):

You can set the attributes in request

`request.setAttribute("attr",val);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet_path");
rd.forward(request,response);`

Comment: Exact answer, elaborate little bit :)

Comment: Suppose if we have servlet S1 & S2 and we want to pass value from S1 to S2 then in S1 we would write the above code and in S2 we would fetch the value using 'request.getAttribute("attr")'

Comment: Thanks first, but I have one thing clear. In servlets s1 I have the variable "finals" I want to go to the servlet s2, then I do:
request.setAttribute ("attr", finals);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher ("C: / Users / thesis / workspace / W7TurismoServer / src / packserver / S2");
rd.forward (request, response);

S2 as I can recall "finals"? Thanks again.

Comment: In RequestDispatcher you have to provide the path of the servlet using the context root of your web application and not the complete file path. And also you can name attr attribute to the one that best suits to you.

Answer (score 0):

Example from [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html):

```
    URL yahoo = new URL("http://localhost:portnumber/context/urlpattern/s?x="+x+"&y="+y);
    URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
```

From your perspective, servlet is just an URL on some server. As for not waiting for a response - read about Java threads.
Use the above code in the method m(x,y)